# Configure AWS EMR spark with aws sts assume-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, aws-sts

I am trying to read a file from s3 bucket with is in another AWS Account.

Steps:

1. Generated access id, access key secret and token using **`aws sts assume-role`** command
2. Set following variables:

   ```
   export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
   export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
   export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=
   ```
3. `aws s3 ls s3://...`
4. reading file in **spark-shell**

   ```
   sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "XXX")
   sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "XXX")
   sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.session.token", "XXX")
   spark.read.parquet("file location")
   ```

Up to step 3 its working fine.

I am unable to read the file in spark-shell.
I am using **spark version: 2.4.3**. Please let me know what i am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

**Error log:**

```
    Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

Comment: How did you call aws sts assume-role? On EMR?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your credential was deleted.

You can also see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/security-cross-account.html